# mdcolors not working in mddialog for Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I have an mddialog that tries to use md-colors to set a backGround color of a div in a dialog.  However it is not respecting the current theme, instead defaulting to the blue theme.

```
md-colors="{backgroundColor: 'primary'}"
```

Is this a known issue?  Is there a workaround?

Using version 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/qaEmgq?editors=1010)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="TasksController as vm" class="md-padding" ng-cloak="" ng-app="app">
   <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="vm.show($event)">
      Custom Dialog
    </md-button>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
    <md-dialog aria-label="Test" layout-margin layout="column" layout-align="center center">
        <div style="width:100px; height:100px;"  md-colors="::{background: 'altTheme-primary-700'}"></div>
    </md-dialog>
  </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('altTheme')
    .primaryPalette('purple')

  $mdThemingProvider.setDefaultTheme('altTheme');
})

.controller('TasksController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.show = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      templateUrl: 'test.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Looks like I'll need to move my dialog into an ng-template block.

Comment: @ed4becky You shouldn't need to. It could be inline. How have you set it up?

Comment: Ok, but if I don't have the '$event' argument, for example, the $mdDialog.show() is trigged on my controller loading??